# Does this site support questions related to illegal/unsolicited uses of Tor?

Tags: discussion, support

[This](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/8607/access-problem-to-solve) question, although seems to be an 'Unable to connect' issue, is about Adult (probably CP) site.

What is the community's stand on entertaining such 'dark' uses of Tor?

Personally, I think if a question looks to be dealing with such matters, it should be closed.

Answer (score 3):

I think questions of the "This one specific Hidden Service isn't loading" variety would be off-topic either way. These are often temporary or unstable, and trying to diagnose every single "site down" case would be impractical.

In a more general sense, our job is not to judge content or actions. Tor protects users from government restrictions of free speech, and "illegal/unsolicited" usage would vary from country to country.

That said, I think there's a level of common sense that "How do I hide my child porn?" or "Can Tor help me kill my spouse?" questions would be flagged and closed. If enough of the community agrees I'll go ahead and add that to [What topics can I ask about here?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center and as an Off-Topic Close Reason.